# Вывод ошибки при переполнении буфера

Tags: c

Программа ниже сортирует строку на слова и числа. Максимальная длинна строки - `101` символ. Нужно чтобы при превышении этого кол-ва, программа не прекращала работу а выводила ошибку используя `BUFMAX` - аля `printf ("Error");`

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf, scanf, sscanf
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi

#define BUFMAX 101 //Max value of symbols

int isNumber (const char *buf) {

int i = 0;

while (buf[i] != '\0') {

    if ( buf[i] < '0' || buf[i] > '9' )
        {
        return 0;
        }
    else i++;
    }
return 1;
}

int main (void) {

char buf[101];  // Max length

while(scanf("%s", buf) != EOF) {  // Scanning string until end of string.
     if (isNumber(buf))  // If found number - print.
        {
            printf ("number: %u", atoi(buf)) ;
        }
        else // If not all of above - just word.
        {
            printf ("word: %s",buf);
        }
        printf("\n");
   } // end of while
return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: И? Не ясно в чем проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. Вам нельзя допускать реального переполнения буфера, потому что это ведёт к неопределённому поведению программы.

Попробуйте вот какую стратегию:

1. Заведите буфер на один символ длиннее, чем ваш планируемый максимум, плюс ещё один символ под финальный `\0`. Для вашего случая это будет, например, 102.
2. При считывании через `scanf` укажите максимальную длину: если это 101, то `scanf("%101s", buf);`. (Вы можете даже извратиться с препроцессором и использовать `scanf("%" #BUFSIZE "s", buf);`.) Не забудьте, что `scanf` дописывает в конце `\0`, так что он использует все 102 символа.
3. После чтения опросите длину введённой строки. Если она больше 100 — пользователь ввёл слишком много, регистрируйте переполнение.

Таким образом, вы получили логическое, а не реальное переполнение буфера.

Comment: Или используйте scanf_s. Мне прям смешно иногда, что разработчики пытаются обезопасить программу, а все (я тоже в 100% случаев) применяют scanf=)

Comment: @АлексейСаровский: По сути, лучше один раз написать и отладить безопасную обёртку.

Comment: согласен. Видел у товарищей самодельный маленький небольшой "фрэймворк", где самые любимые функции самописные собраны (в том числе обертки над стандартными). Очень удобно.

Comment: @VladD все что Вы написали, я это понимал, мне как раз нужно было правильно зарегистрировать это переполнение. Не знаю как правильно это сделать, через условие или в этом же цикле как-то извернуться.

Comment: @Danya: Ну это уже логика вашей программы, зависит только от вас. Например, вы можете в цикле предлагать пользователю ввести строку, и если зарегистрировано переполнение, наругаться и попросить вводить снова, пока не введёт нормально. Не забудьте после ввода с переполнением пропустить «лишние» символы.